# terminal http command

Tags: command-line

I've seen someone uses this format to make http requests:

```
http POST http://url.com arg=value
```

I can't seem to find how to do that

google searches only show cUrl and wget. Also tried downloading http package but there is none.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install the package `httpie` to use the [http](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/http.1.html) command.

Answer (score 4):

## Quick Answer:

Using `apt`:

```
apt-get install httpie
```

Or using `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
pip install --upgrade httpie
```